# Problem to see webparts with users without privileges

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I'm using sharepoint online webparts created with react

I'm developing webparts for sharepoint, at first I tried with an empty webpart, just the auto generated one with yo @microsoft/sharepoint, when I upload it to the appCatalog and I deploy it on one Page, I can see it without any problem if I'm admin

but if I'm not admin I'm seeing this error

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: Failed to load component
>   "b14c194f-ec3a-48e6-ade1-575d96b30ce1" (FormularioDes). Original
>   error: Failed to load path dependency
>   "FormularioDesglosesWebPartStrings" from component
>   "b14c194f-ec3a-48e6-ade1-575d96b30ce1" (FormularioDesglosesWebPart).
>   Original error: Error loading
>   id.invalid/b14c194f-ec3a-48e6-ade1-_0.0.1/FormularioDes Unable to load
>   script

this is my package.json

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package- 
 solution.schema.json",
"solution": {
"name": "formulario-des-client-side-solution",
"id": "id-here",
"version": "1.0.0.0",
"includeClientSideAssets": true,
"skipFeatureDeployment": true,
"isDomainIsolated": false
},
"paths": {
"zippedPackage": "solution/formulario-des.sppkg"
 }
}
```

edit: I've tried without isDomainIsolated, same error

Comment: Where are you uploading your assets for this solution?

Comment: Does your normal user has read access on App catalog? Try giving read permission on app catalog.

Comment: I'm uploading the solution on app catalog, the problem is that the client doesn't want to give permissions to each user because there are too much users